# Existence of minimal ideal with a specific property

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring, $I\subset R$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. Consider the set $\Gamma_I$ of all ideals $J\subset R$ such that $J+I\subset R$ is a maximal ideal. It is clear that $\Gamma$ is not empty (any maximal ideal containing $I$ belongs to $\Gamma_I$).

My question is, is it always the case that $\Gamma_I$ contains a minimal element? in other words, if $\{J_i\}_{i\in X}$ is a collection of ideals satisfying this property (i.e. $J_i+I$ is a maximal ideal for every $i\in X$), does it follow that the intersection $\cap_{i\in X} J_i$ also does have this property (i..e $\cap_{i\in X}J_i+I$ is a maximal ideal)?

If not, are there any conditions on $R$ (or $I$) that ensures that this holds?

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}$, consider $I=6\mathbb{Z}$, the only elements of $T_{I}$ are $2\mathbb{Z};3\mathbb{Z}$, and the intersection is again $I$. Remark that in order for the minimal element to exist, we must have: $$\forall i_{0}\in X, I+\cap_{i\in X}J_{i} = I+J_{i_{0}}$$

Comment: @belkacemabderrahmane Thanks a lot! For my purposes, I had in mind that $I$ is maximal, and hence elements in $\Gamma_I$ would be subideals of $I$. In this case, your counter-example does not answer the question (at least the refined one). I added the condition that $I$ is maximal to the question.

Comment: Now your question doesn't make sense. It now reduces to 'is there a minimal ideal lying jn a fixed maximal ideal I', which is rarely true. Also, right now you are not excluding the zero ideal. And also this question doesn't reduce to whether some infinite intersection satisfies some property, because it may be zero.